# Xamarin update 6.2 build 1829

Tags: xamarin, crash, fatal-error

Since the update this week, my main app won't run in debug mode - it crashes Xamarin with no messages - just "A fatal error has occurred".  Does anyone know what has caused it and how can I remedy it?  Sorry for the lack of info - stepping through what I can, it fails in random places but generally loading one of 3 views.

Neil

Comment: Do you have a log? Which operating system? What platform is this - Xamarin.Forms? Xamarin.Android? Does it get to your application code at all or does it "insta-crash" when you try to run it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks EJoshuaS.  I'm using Sierra 10.12.3.  No logs.  applied a Monomac patch today (4.8.0495 I think) and that seems to have resolved it.